# NDSolve issues for three differential equations in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I'm still very new to working with Mathematica and i'm going over this a lot and i don't really understand what i am (very clearly) doing wrong.

I was basically trying to recreate a result obtaining three functions, that i call C1, C2 and f:

I use constraints for the derivatives of C1 and C2 and an initial value for f. The other i thing i needed to take care of was to make sure that when f*C22 = 1, which creates a division by zero, that i'd make the whole equation for C1' go to zero. (Technically the theory is that you define Lambda/p to be something that is symmetric to the rest of the second term of that equation for a specific value of x where this singularity comes up).

I'm very sorry for this but thanks in advance.

```
c = 2; \[Lambda] = 1; k = 1; Dp = 0.5; pm = 1;

NDSolve[{C1'[x] == pm*((1 - f[x]*C2[x]^2)^(-1/2) )* (C2[x]*((C2[x] - c)^2 - C1[x]^2) + 2*(\[Lambda]/k)*C2[x] + (Dp/k) - 2*(1 - f[x]*C2[x]^2)*(C1[x] - C2[x])/f[x]), 
C2'[x] == pm*2*((1 - f[x]*C2[x]^2)^(1/2))*(C1[x] - C2[x])/f[x], 
f'[x] == pm*4*(1 - f[x]*C2[x]^2)^(1/2),
C2'[0.] == (1/3)*C1'[0.], C2'[1] == (1/3)*C1'[1], f[0.] == 0.1, 
WhenEvent[C2[x]^2 == 1/f[x], {C1'[x] == 0.}]},
{C1[x], C2[x], f[x]}, {x, 0., 1}, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}]
```

Comment: If you look carefully at the documentation for `WhenEvent` you should see that the second argument is of the form `C1'[x]->0` rather than `C1'[x] == 0`. That doesn't deal with the stream of 1/0 errors, probably because of all of your denominators, but perhaps this will be the first step.